# SPARK: Cast error usando insert: Java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

Tags: string, insert, cast, spark, hive

He estado luchando por un tiempo con este maldito error que surge al intentar insertar en una tabla de Hive con Spark (versión 1.6.0):

-java.lang.String no se puede convertir a org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String

Estoy tratando de insertar desde una tabla con campos como un tipo de cadena en otra con exactamente el mismo tipo. Estoy ejecutando este proceso a través de NiFi.

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea de por qué esto podría estar sucediendo? ¿Alguna vez has peleado con algo como esto?

POR FAVOR SE NECESITA AYUDA!!!

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Estás en [es.so], por lo cual debes publicar tu pregunta en castellano o terminará cerrada. Además, te invito a leer [ask], realizar el [tour] y leer [mcve]. Saludos

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.